# how i can color the textblock while mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a style that will make the textblock on mouse over underligned can we change the forecolor on mouse over of this textblock using WPF or i will need to change it programmatically ? here the style that i have

```
  <TextBlock Text="Hurrah">
   <TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add following line in your trigger

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="CadetBlue"/>
```